# Xcode 5 iOS 5 - support neither for device nor for simulator?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-simulator, xcode5, osx-mavericks

I have couple of apps that run on iOS 5 through 7. It's already pain maintaining different set of apis.

On my new OS X Mavericks box with Xcode 5, it simply refuses to show me iOS 5 simulator.

To add to that pain, when I attach my iOS 5 device, my app simply crash complaining about iOS 6 features (not present in iOS 5 - UICollectionView for example).

Here is the crash log on my iOS 5 device:

```
Symbol not found: _UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
```

Note that for the last problem - I have all conditional compiling MACROS in my code. Such as, I wrap my UICollectionView code between:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_6_0
#endif
```

I also do the runtime check to see if the class exist:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UICollectionView"))
```

I am sure this problem didn't exist on my older box with Xcode 5 and 4.6 (OS X Lion). But I simply can't get it now, and this issue is driving me crazy as it leaves me without iOS 5 support.

What to do?

Comment: Go to preference>Downloads and install the simulators.

Comment: it only shows simulators >6.0. I even got iOS 5 SDK from a source and can see it as a choice in Schemes, but when I launch the app it is 6.0 only.

Comment: If it's crashing at runtime your runtime checks are evidently not working or complete.

Comment: @Kevin, I updated my question with crash log. I am sure every time I do something with my collection view property variable, I include the runtime check mentioned. May there be any hidden place which is left out?

Answer (score 1):

you could download XCode 4.6.3 from developer.apple.com

Comment: Of course, it's a pain to use XCode 4 file formats (project, nibs...).

Comment: Apple App Store [requires](http://www.macworld.com/article/2080865/apple-requiring-app-submissions-to-be-optimized-for-ios-7-by-feb-1.html) apps and updates be built with Xcode 5 as of 2014-02-01.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking if you can call the method. I use this sort of thing:

```
if ([UICollectionView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:)])
```

Or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

I got around the problem by linking UIKit as Optional framework instead of Required.

Strange, but true.